# How can I set the value of an input time by adding minutes on another input time

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, time

I'm trying to change the link to the times' input. When I choose an hour in the eventStartTime, I would like to fill, depend of a time passing through the minutesToHours function (in minutes), the eventEndTime (an addition: the eventStartTime + the minutes I've added)

For example : I want to add 120 minutes. I choose an start hours (the first input), then I want to automatically fill the end hours (the second input) with an addition between the minutes I added and the start hours I choose,

I have tried to do it by myself, but I didn't get any results :

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('#eventStart').on('input', function () {
            var convertDuration = minuteToHours(6);
            $('#eventEnd').val($(this).val() + moment(convertDuration).format('HH:mm'));
        });
});
function minuteToHours(num) {
            var hours = Math.floor(num / 60);
            var minutes = num % 60;
            return hours + ":" + minutes;
        };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label class="form-label" for="eventStart">Start</label>
             <input class="form-control" id="eventStart" type="time">
          </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="form-group">
               <label class="form-label" for="eventEnd">End</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="eventEnd" type="time">
         </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need the date too, there are scenarios where after adding minutes the day will change.
Try this:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
         $('#eventStart').on('input', function () {
                //var convertDuration = minuteToHours(6);
                const now = new Date();
                const [hour, minutes] = $(this).val().split(":");
                now.setHours(hour);
                now.setMinutes(minutes);
                const newDate = addMinutes(now, 120);
                $('#eventEnd').val(`${newDate.getHours().toString().padStart(2, 0)}:${newDate.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, 0)}`);
            });
    });
    
    function addMinutes(date, minutes) {
      const minuteInMillisecons = minutes * 1000 * 60;
      const newDate = new Date(date.valueOf() + minuteInMillisecons);
      return newDate;
    }
```

Comment: You can add the minutes when setting the hours, e.g. `now.setHours(hour, minutes + Number(minutes))` and can format the time using `now.toLocaleString('en', {hour:'2-digit', minute:'2-digit', hour12:false})`. :-)